# How to assign a user a role in a server from a direct message discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am trying to make a bot where if a user direct messages the bot, it will give them a role in a server that both the user and the bot are in. I tried to just add the role based on the role ID but that did not work.

Here is an example of what I was thinking which could maybe help explain it a bit better.

```
role = (role ID)

member = message.author
await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Now keep in mind this will be happening in a direct message, and not in a server where this would be much easier.

If anyone knows how to do this or has any ideas, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What if the user and the bot share many servers?  Would you grant roles in all the common servers, or somehow choose?  Or would this just be for one server hardcoded in the bot?

Comment: This is for specifically one server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we record the ids and then access the appropriate objects when we recieve the command.

```
target_server_id = "123..."
target_role_id   = "456..."

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def gimmieRole(ctx):
    if not ctx.message.channel.is_private:
        await bot.say("Private command only")
    server = await bot.get_Server(target_server_id)
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, id=target_role_id)
    member = server.get_member(ctx.message.author.id)
    if member:
        await bot.add_roles(member, role)
    else:
        await bot.say("You are not a member")
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much! I searched all over for this.

Comment: Could you maybe show the entire context of the code? I am running into a few issues with my methods. Maybe showing imports would help?