# Discord.Py On Join commands

Tags: python, discord

I have a discord bot, and I want it to do something like

```
once a member joins
    DM member (message)
if member replies with key
    give them this role
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far (any code to show)? Also, what do you mean by `if member replies with key give them this role`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the function `on_member_join()`.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    pass
```

Then put the code message sending/receiving code in there. With your example you would do:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await client.send_message(member, 'Prompt.')
    m = await client.wait_for_message(author=member, channel=member)
    if m.content == 'key':
        # give the user the role
        await client.send_message(member, 'Role added')
    else:
        await client.send_message(member, 'Incorrect key')
```

To find out how to give a user a role from a dm to a server, read this question: [How To Assign A User A Role In A Server From A Direct Message - Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737572/how-to-assign-a-user-a-role-in-a-server-from-a-direct-message-discord-py?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send("hello")
```

This code sends hello to the user when he/she joins the server.
Hope this is helpful for everybody